# How to wrap this repeated lines of code in Unity in a simple method?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, methods

I made this mess that works fine, but is a pain to read and modify.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (gunController.isGrabbed)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PlayerBullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy1")) //Player to Enemy fire
        {
            enemy1.enemyHealth -= gunController.gunDamage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy1Bullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) //Enemy to player fire
        {
            player.playerHealth -= gunController.gunDamage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }

    }
    else if(shotgunController.isGrabbed)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PlayerBullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy1")) //Player to Enemy fire
        {
            enemy1.enemyHealth -= shotgunController.gunDamage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy1Bullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) //Enemy to player fire
        {
            player.playerHealth -= shotgunController.gunDamage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }

    } else if (uziController.isGrabbed)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PlayerBullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy1")) //Player to Enemy fire
        {
            enemy1.enemyHealth -= uziController.gunDamage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy1Bullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) //Enemy to player fire
        {
            player.playerHealth -= uziController.gunDamage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Basically there's one Controller for each weapon (gun, shotgun, uzi) and the code is the same for all of them, the only thing that changes is the Controller name.

So my idea was to create a method and pass as a parameter a List<> of controllers and with a foreach iterate to the same code three times. But I can't pass a List since the types of the Controller are unique, I can't store in a List various types of controllers.

I don't know if there's a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Can you show us your classes a little bit more ? I mean are those `gun`/`shotgun`/`uzi` controllers inheriting the same base class ? In which class is this method ?

Comment: If they all have the same methods on them, why not extract an interface? Then you can treat them all the same as long as you only care about the interface.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the controllers don't share a common base class or interface,

```
private void doDamage(bool isGrabbed, int damage)
{
    if (isGrabbed)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PlayerBullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy1")) //Player to Enemy fire
        {
            enemy1.enemyHealth -= damage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy1Bullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) //Enemy to player fire
        {
            player.playerHealth -= damage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }

    }

}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    doDamage(gunController.isGrabbed, gunController.gunDamage);
    doDamage(shotgunController.isGrabbed, shotgunController.gunDamage);
    doDamage(uziController.isGrabbed,uziController.gunDamage);
}
```

If the controllers share the same base class (or are instances of the same class), you can just

```
private void doDamage(Controller controller)
{
    if (controller.isGrabbed)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PlayerBullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy1")) //Player to Enemy fire
        {
            enemy1.enemyHealth -= controller.damage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy1Bullet") && gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) //Enemy to player fire
        {
            player.playerHealth -= controller.damage;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }           
}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    doDamage(gunController);
    doDamage(shotgunController);
    doDamage(uziController);
}
```

If `Controller` is a component, you could just `GetComponents` to get all of the them and then loop through the collection, calling `doDamage` for each of them.

Comment: Being pedantic but the `doDamage` methods should be capitalized as it's C# :)

Comment: @akaBase that is personal preference.

Comment: Thank you I understand it better now!

Comment: @3Dave The [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) Say otherwise?

Comment: @akaBase There is no technical requirement regarding case or naming convention in C#. You'll find that these vary greatly between different organizations and developers in this as in any other language. Microsoft's guide is clear and a perfectly valid approach, but it's not the only way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

Consider setting up a base class called e.g. `WeaponController` or `Controller`. Now put all generic stuff into it. Then create a distinct class per weapon type (if really needed; using Prefabs may also be workable, try look into those). Have these classes inherit from WeaponController, then add their own weapon-type-specific stuff on top. For your generic management, like the Player holding a weapon, you now only need to use the `WeaponController` class (`GetComponent<WeaponController>()`) -- make those parts of your code not care about the specifics, but let specifics be handled inside the specific class like ShotgunController. E.g.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] AudioSource dropSound = null;
    protected Rigidbody body = null;
    protected int bullets = 10;
    protected float reloadSeconds = 0.5f;

    protected virtual void Fire()
    {
        if (bullets > 0)
        {
            bullets--;
            FireBullet();
        }
    }

    // etc.
}
```

and

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ShotgunController : WeaponController
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject bulletShellPrefab = null;

    protected override void Fire()
    {
        base.Fire();
        EmitBulletShell();
    }

    void EmitBulletShell()
    {
        // Maybe you only want shotguns to emit bullet shells,
        // so that code goes here.
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful!